# Model Name: MacBook Air Model Identifier: MacBookAir4,2 Processor Name: Intel Core i7 Processor Speed: 1.8 GHz

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, battery

Battery life catastrophic since upgrade to Yosemite - activity monitor shows 'spotlight web content' items using large amounts of CPU for webpages that are not even open?? Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 1):

Spotlight is re-indexing after the upgrade, which means it's busy all the time, impacting performance and battery life. Never try to judge the performance or battery impact of any major OS X upgrade until the machine has been turned on but idle for at least a week, to give time for the re-indexing to complete.

Comment: I installed on 16/10 release date - would it take this long???

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so, if it's been kept awake all the time and not had the lid closed to put it to sleep. If it's been asleep then you need to be counting the time it's been awake for, not the total elapsed time.